# How to create a sortable picture gallery?

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, image-gallery

I want to create a youtuber gallery (or table I don't know) with avatar pictures that would be sortable by sexe, country, age... (ideally with settings on the side).

Pictures would include interactive several links and I would also like visitors to know what youtubers are live when consulting the list/table.

Thanks a lot in advance... ))

Comment: What have you tried so far? This doesn't really sound like a programming problem, yet. It's more like you're asking for library/plugin-recommendations. You'll generally get more/better answers if you provide a concrete problem. Also, your question will be more valuable to others in the future.

Comment: I'm on wordpress using Beaver Builder as a page builder and trying to find the best way to list youtubers in a gallery that people could set by topic, country... so the first pics corresponding to the settings appear on top and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you more than a library recommendation here, but I think something like this is the way to go: Have a look at [Isotope](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/), a JS library to generate *"Filter & sort magical layouts"*. It looks pretty much like what you want.
The demo on the site linked above basically says it all. You can see the code for the demo in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nFrte) (also taken from the site linked above).

How it works is that you feed your markup with meta data for the respective elements and the library gives you the filter & sort functionality and displays a grid layout with your elements:

```html
<div class="element-item metalloid " data-category="metalloid">
    <h3 class="name">Tellurium</h3>
    <p class="symbol">Te</p>
    <p class="number">52</p>
    <p class="weight">127.6</p>
</div>
```

Then it's simple to have filter buttons for the grid like this:

```html
<button class="button" data-filter=".metal">metal</button>
```

*(samples from the codepen!)*

I hope this hint helps you - it certainly gives you more control then ready-made Youtube gallery (if there is one at all, I don't know) - but in turn you'll have to get your hands a little dirty writing up the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jQuery UI sortables "Display as Grid":

https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#display-grid

You can do something like this:

```
    <ul id="sortable">
        <li class="ui-state-default">
            <img src="something.png">
        </li>
    </ul>
```

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
    $( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
  } );
```

```css
#sortable { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0; 
  width: 450px; 
}
 #sortable li { 
   margin: 3px 3px 3px 0; 
   padding: 1px; 
   float: left; 
   width: 100px; 
   height: 90px; 
   font-size: 4em; 
   text-align: center;
   background: #ddd;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>
```